# after concat the values changed to float and not remain in int(attempted to convert it before concat.)

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I first attempted to change the information(series) back to int and then after i cncat it back, it changed back to float>

```
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3, None,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'code': ['a{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(10)]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['a{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(5)]})

df1['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['a'], errors='coerce')
df1_temp = df1.dropna(subset=['a'])
df1_temp_2 = df1[df1['a'].isnull()]
df1_temp['a'] = df1_temp['a'].astype(int)
df1_a = pd.concat([df1_temp, df1_temp_2], axis=0)
df1_a.sort_index(axis=0)
df1_a
```

output:

```
    a   code
0   1.0 a1
1   2.0 a2
2   3.0 a3
3   NaN a4
4   5.0 a5
5   6.0 a6
6   7.0 a7
7   8.0 a8
8   9.0 a9
9   10.0    a10
```

Expected:

```
    a   code
0   1   a1
1   2   a2
2   3   a3
3   NaN a4
4   5   a5
5   6   a6
6   7   a7
7   8   a8
8   9   a9
9   10  a10
```

Any good suggestion? shorter and more pandas way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in pandas 0.24+ with [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df1['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['a'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
print (df1)
     a code
0    1   a1
1    2   a2
2    3   a3
3  NaN   a4
4    5   a5
5    6   a6
6    7   a7
7    8   a8
8    9   a9
9   10  a10
```

EDIT: If want convert integers in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (if integers was written to file):

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3, None,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'code': ['a{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(10)]})
df1['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['a'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')

df1.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'a':'Int64'})
print (df)
     a code
0    1   a1
1    2   a2
2    3   a3
3  NaN   a4
4    5   a5
5    6   a6
6    7   a7
7    8   a8
8    9   a9
9   10  a10
```

Comment: There is an issue, after I saved it to a csv file using to_csv with encoding='utf-8'. and then reopen it back with read_csv, all the output returns back to float. Any idea why?

Comment: @Anonymous - Because `read_csv` by default converting empty values to `NaN`s.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is before save it was [1,3,4,5,6,7] in int64 format, but when read_csv it became [1.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]

Comment: @Anonymous - Yes, it is expected. Because in csv all values are saved like strings. And then `read_csv` parse it. So parser use default `NaN`s like floats and then  is created float column.

Comment: is there a way to make it so that after open it it wont become float?>